# Checking whether the PC is connected on LAN or not

Tags: c#, .net, networking

I want to ask 2 questions and I would be thankful if somebody can reply.

1. How can I check (using C#) whether the PC is connected to LAN or not?
2. How can I check (using C#) my PC is connected on LAN or not

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314213/checking-network-status-in-c -- if this doesn't answer your question fully, you may want to edit it to make the difference between question #1 and #2 apparent...

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
```

Comment: Wasn't it supposed to say, if you have any network connection at all?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use Ping to check whether a PC is connected to the LAN. Here's a sample:

```
var ping = new Ping();
var options = new PingOptions { DontFragment = true };

//just need some data. this sends 10 bytes.
var buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes( new string( 'z', 10 ) );
var host = "127.0.0.1";

try
{
    var reply = ping.Send( host, 60, buffer, options );
    if ( reply == null )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Reply was null" );
        return;
    }

    if ( reply.Status == IPStatus.Success )
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Ping was successful." );
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show( "Ping failed." );
    }
}
catch ( Exception ex )
{
    MessageBox.Show( ex.Message );
}
```

To check if you own machine was connected, you could do the same to an address you know should resolve like say the domain controller.

Comment: @Thomas this code is sending ping successful even if i remove the lan cable from my PC

Comment: That's because I used 127.0.0.1 merely for illustration purposes. You would need to replace that IP with one on the network like say a domain controller.

Answer (score 1):

Use `System.Net.NetworkInformation` namespace's ping facility. For more refer [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)