# Lan connection is up or down

Tags: c#, c++, networking, windows-ce

What is the way to find out if the LAN connection is up or down in wince 7 with c++ or c#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ipConfig command line tool from your c# or c++ application, it provides the status of all network adapters.

This question may be useful: [Checking network status in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314213/checking-network-status-in-c-sharp)

> ```
> bool networkUp
>     = System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();
> ```

Comment: I can't access System.Net.NetworkInformation, I added system.dll, I need to add any other dll?

Comment: this function isn't available in the .NET CF, which is what the author would be using.

Comment: Always, my simple solutions got reputation!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
try
{
System.Net.IPHostEntry entry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostByName("hostname");
// found host
}
catch(System.Net.Socket.SocketException)
{
//host not found == LAN not connected!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`NetworkChange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) class in .NET. For Lan connection, use [`NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.aspx) method.

```
Return Value
Type: System.Boolean
true if a network connection is available; otherwise, false.
```

Also take a look those;

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged
```

Comment: I can't access System.Net.NetworkInformation, I added system.dll, I need to add any other dll?

Comment: Did you add as a namespace `using System.Net.NetworkInformation;` ?